# My 16 year old red eared slider hasn't laid eggs in years

Tags: health, reptiles, turtles, reproduction

Shes been acting crazy, trying to get out of her tank and being a picky eater. I just started reading about her symptoms and discovered that she could be eggbound. Until now, I had no idea that this was even a possibility.

When I first got her Google wasn't a thing, I just bought books about red eared sliders and felt pretty confident and competent. Shes never even seen a vet before, shes always had a healthy appetite, sleep patterns. Never felt the need to take her. Have I been neglecting her for 16 YEARS?! When I got her, I literally took her off of a tweakers porch. They had her in a cut off gallon jug outside in December. She was about the size of a 50 cent piece and now she's 11 inches long.

She has laid eggs in the past, in her tank, and she has always eaten them. Please help! I feel so bad, do turtles have changes in hormones like menopause? I just assumed she outgrew it and now I'm freaking out! Is she egg bound? She hasn't laid eggs in years. Do turtles become infertile with age like women do?

Comment: When you say she's acting crazy and trying to get out of the tank, is she also trying to dig a nest? Does she have a place to dig?

Comment: At first I thought she was trying to dig, shes got a sand box but she doesn't want anything to do with that either. She just wants to be covered, under the dresser, under the table, even under a blanket.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you couldn't be neglecting her for years, she would have shown some symptoms for sure. My 17 year old RES has stopped laying eggs for years too, and I haven't found a good explanation for this yet. She laid some beautiful clutches of eggs for about 3 years and then for the last 5 or more years, she hasn't. She eats well (voraciously!) and has some mood swings (wants to be by herself at times, at other times follows me around, sometimes just wants to be in her tank, and sometimes sits with me in the sun for hours) so I assume she is well and happy. But if you have found a good reason for her behaviour, or found that there was something to be done better, please do share.

I realise I'm posting many months after your question, so I hope yours is well and wish her many more healthy and happy years with you :)